# Selection order for an Insert Into SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2, insert-into

I have a query in which I create a table and then insert data into it. My question is this, I have one column where I need to make the data distinct, my output seems to be working correctly but I would like clarification on if this is an acceptable practice.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(
MRN VARCHAR(20)
, [ENCOUNTER] VARCHAR(200)
, ...
, ...
, ...
)

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT
A.Med_Rec_No
, A.[VISIT ID]
, ...
, ...
, ...
)

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PTNO_NUM AS [VISIT ID] -- MUST I CHANGE THE ORDER?
    , PAV.Med_Rec_No                           -- MUST I CHANGE THE ORDER?
    , ...
    , ...
    , ...
)
```

Does the `INSERT INTO @T1 SELECT` take care of the ordering for me, meaning does it really matter what order I `SELECT` items in the `FROM` statement as long as my `INSESRT INTO` matches what my `DECLARE @T1 TABLE` says?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `INSERT INTO FROM SELECT` you **MUST** match order of columns in `SELECT` statement as they are in `INSERT` statement.

Now on other hand you not required to match column order in `INSERT` statement to what is in `CREATE TABLE`.

It is always recommended to specify `COLUMN` in `INSERT` statement. Otherwise you assuming that what you selecting matches column order in table that you are inserting into.

In your case you should modify your query like so.

```
INSERT INTO @T1 (MRN, Encounter)
SELECT
A.Med_Rec_No
, A.[VISIT ID]
, ...
, ...
, ...
)

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PTNO_NUM AS [VISIT ID] 
    , PAV.Med_Rec_No                          
    , ...
    , ...
    , ...
)
```

as alternative you can modify order of column in `INSERT` clause

```
INSERT INTO @T1 (Encounter,MRN)
SELECT
A.[VISIT ID]
,A.Med_Rec_No 
, ...
, ...
, ...
)

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PTNO_NUM AS [VISIT ID] 
    , PAV.Med_Rec_No                          
    , ...
    , ...
    , ...
)
```